# htaccess query string redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

I am trying to redirect http://example.com/for-sale/?property=1234 to http://example.com/for-sale/property-name/ in .htaccess, using RewriteCond and RewriteRule. This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(property=1234)
RewriteRule ^$ /for-sale/property-name/? [R=301,L]
```

This does not work. I can redirect ?property=1234 to for-sale/property-name/ but how do I get it to work with /for-sale/ in the un-redirected URL? I've tried various combinations of for-sale in the RewriteRule but without success.
Thanks.
All my links are now broken so I would really appreciate some advice. Thanks.

Comment: No, it's generated by WordPress and comes from the 'rewrite' parameter in 'register_post_type'. I found the problem and fixed it, please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wordpress site, so the first mistake was to do the rewrites after wordpress does its rewrites. Second mistake was in the RewriteRule. Here is the working code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} property=1234$
RewriteRule ^for-sale/?$ /for-sale/property-name/? [R=301,L]

 ... my other rewrites

</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This works. Hope it helps someone else out.